# How to execute a filter by function return value in list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Below is the basic logic:

```
result = []

for item in item_lst:
    code = foo(item)
    if code != -1:
        result.append(code)
```

With list comprehension, I should write twice:

```
result = [foo(item) for item in item_lst]
result = [code for code in result if code != -1]
```

Or

```
result = [foo(item) for item in item_lst if foo(item) != -1]
```

Which will call function foo twice.

Is there any better solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to avoid creating a second list:

```
result = [code for code in (foo(item) for item in item_ls) if code != -1]
```

Here:

```
(foo(item) for item in item_ls)
```

is a generator expression. No intermediate list is created. This potentially helps to save memory.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` and `map`, it is shorter and maybe clearer:

```
restuls = filter(lambda x: x != -1, map(foo, item_ls))
```

this would work for python3
for python 2 consider using `itertools.imap` to avoid intermediate list creation:

```
from itertools import imap
restuls = filter(lambda x: x != -1, imap(foo, item_ls))
```

Comment: I honestly love the `filter` / `map` combo. So intuitive to use these if you come from a functional programming background.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try:

```
[x for x in [foo(item) for item in item_lst] if x != -1]
```

Comment: doesn't it create intermediate list structure?

Comment: yes, it does create an intermediate list. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48019193/2843896 is the best way